# I need help determining the query for a self-join with a date-range limiter

Tags: sql, linq, self-join

Suppose I have a table with four columns: ID, ParentID, Timestamp, Value. The ParentID changes the meaning of value. I need to return all the entries from this table where their ParentID = 1 and their Timestamp is within the Timestamps of the items in the table where ParentID = 2 and those items with ParentID.Value > 10.

For example, here is some data:

```
ID    ParentID    TimeStamp    Value
1     1           51           1
2     2           52           11
3     1           53           2
4     1           54           3
5     2           55           9
6     1           56           4
7     2           57           12
8     1           58           5
9     1           53.5         1
```

I need a query that returns me those rows with IDs 3, 4, 8, and 9. What would this query look like in SQL or LINQ? Is it permissible to join on yourself and would you use that approach here? I'm stuck on how to determine the timestamp ranges. I'm using Sqlite. Thanks.

Clarification: I want to filter by the most recent (judged by timestamp) row with ParentID = 2.

Comment: The value 56 is "within the Timestamps of the items in the table where ParentID = 2 and those items with ParentID.Value > 10", so ID=6 should be in the result set according to this criterion.

Comment: @gcbenison: On the other hand, the `ID=8` row doesn't seem to satisfy the condition. My guess is, the OP meant to say `3, 4, 6, and 9` instead of `3, 4, 8, and 9`.

Comment: gcbenison & Andriy M, you misunderstood the question. Obviously I was struggling to make it clear, so no hard feelings... "6" is not a valid answer because the preceding row with ParentID == 2 is not greater than 10.

Comment: Your `within the Timestamps` must be what mislead me. That and, perhaps, my insufficient knowledge of English, because I would never have guessed the `8` row was *within* the required timestamps, since there was no `ParentID=2` row after it (and my mind was requiring there to be one for the row in question to be *within*). But, likewise, no hard feelings. If I were to describe your problem, I would likely have struggled even more and the result would hardly have been clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ugly and slow query finds per each ParentID = 1 row adequate ParentID = 2 row and checks if Value is greather than 10; if so, outputs row:

```
select * 
  from table1
 where table1.parentid = 1
   and exists
       (
         select null
         -- Isolate previous ParentID = 2 row
         from
         (
           select p2.value
             from table1 p2
            where p2.timestamp < table1.timestamp
              and p2.parentid = 2
              -- Only one needed
            order by p2.timestamp desc
            limit 1
         ) p2_1
         -- Make sure it has appropriate value
         where p2_1.value > 10
       )
```

This is worth running only once in context of updating a table after a schema change. If you could change ParentID to really be a ParentID (that is, connect record hierarchically) query would become trivial:

```
select Child.*
  from table1 Child
 inner join table1 Parent
    on child.ParentID = Parent.ID
 where Parent.Value > 10
```

ParentID would, of course, had to be found prior to insert and there would be some mathematics involved if business model allows for out of order inserts. If all you expect is simple append of timestamps, this would be the simplest solution.

There is [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/284a3/4) live test of this query.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual problem.  If this is homework, you should tag it as such.

The following query seems to do what you describe:

```
select p1.*
from (select *
      from table t
      where ParentId = 1
     ) p1 cross join
     (select min(TimeStamp) as minTS, max(TimeStamp) as maxTS
      from table t
      where ParentId = 2 and value > 10
     ) p2
where t.TimeStamp between minTS and maxTS
```

And the answer to your question is "yes", all SQL databases support self-joins.

Comment: This is not homework. Fortunately, I wrapped that up a number of years ago! With your proposed query, how are you maintaining the switch effect (for lack of a better term) of the ParentID column? It's off, on, off, on... In other words, I don't want everything between min/max on ParentID 2.

Comment: Your original data has only one timestamp per row.  I see, I interpreted "within the Timestamps of the items . . . " as being "within the range".  I think others interpreted your statement this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ if it doesn't have to be one query this should work:

```
var values = table.Where(a => a.parentid == 2 
                           && a.value > 10)
                  .Select(a.timestamp);

var min = values.Min();
var max = values.Max(); 

var result = table.Where(a => a.parentid == 1
                            && timestamp >= min 
                            && timestamp <= max)
                  .Select(a => a.value);
```

Comment: Joanna, I'm afraid that answer is incorrect. Min/Max won't work because there might be a hole in the middle where we want to exclude data.

Comment: @Brannon - sorry but I don't understand what you mean - as far as I'm aware you haven't mentioned any gaps in data, so don't expect me to just magically know it. If the -1 vote cam from you I will remember not to try and help you again.